# Why did Michael Myers bring Lynda's dead body to his house?

Tags: plot-explanation, halloween-2007

In *Halloween* (2007), generally *Michael Myers* won't bring dead bodies to his house after killing them, but in this movie he brought *Lynda*'s dead body.

Why so?